# What is the difference between = and == in hive

Tags: hive, operators

I accidentally used `==` instead of `=` in one of my HQL query, but shockingly it didn't throw any error but was working as it should have been working for `=`. My question here is why do we have `==` operator in HQL and what is the exact difference between the two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The`=` and `==` operators have the same functionality.
They are implemented by the exact same class.

```
system.registerGenericUDF("=", GenericUDFOPEqual.class);
system.registerGenericUDF("==", GenericUDFOPEqual.class);
```

[FunctionRegistry.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/FunctionRegistry.java)

---

```
+----------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator |    Operand types    |                          Description                           |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| A = B    | All primitive types | TRUE if expression A is equal to expression B otherwise FALSE. |
| A == B   | All primitive types | Synonym for the = operator.                                    |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[LanguageManual UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: Got It. Thanks a lot